# How to add a dynamic select field to widget ui

Tags: magento2

I’ve created a custom widget with ui fields for the widget title, some basic text content.

I need to add a select field with options which I see you add in the widget.xml as a type “select”, but this only allows me to have predefined options

I’m struggling to find any solid information on how I’d make the select field use dynamic data, for example from a custom collection.

How would I do this? Would it be a ui component and somehow tell the select field in my widget to use that?